# tf get for a specific branch

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfvc

Let's say i have two branches: dev and release, once a month it's required to merge all changes from dev to release branch. This could be done manually from visual studio but i want to automate it writing a powershell script that will perform that operation.

In order to merge changes from one branch to another i need to map and "get latest" both branches on one of environments.
That's what i do locally on development environment:

Map server folder($Development/Trunk/Dev) to local one(C:\Temp\MyFolder)

```
.\TF.exe workfold /map /workspace:MyWorkspace "$Development/Trunk/Dev" C:\Temp\MyFolder
```

at the same time i already have $Development/Trunk/Release mapped to another folder let's say C:\Temp\AnotherFolder

when i run

```
.\TF.exe get
```

it downloads files from Release branch to C:\Temp\AnotherFolder

i've tried to run:

```
.\TF.exe get /overwrite C:\Temp\MyFolder /recursive /noprompt
```

with the hope that it will get files from Dev branch (mapping exists)

but what is does - it downloads files from Release branch to the folder C:\Temp\MyFolder. I didn't find in microsoft documentation how do i specify source branch...

Comment: Thanks, but no, found another way which seems to be a better one - see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try to map `$Development/Trunk` to local `C:\Temp\MyFolder`, and then go to folder `C:\Temp\MyFolder` running the following commands:

```
C:\Temp\MyFolder>tf get Dev
C:\Temp\MyFolder>tf get Release
```

Answer (score 0):

TF uses workspace mappings to define from which branch to which local folder it is required to get latest.

So:

1) `tf get` would result to getting latest version on everything that is mapped in a workspace

2) `tf get <path to your local folder where a specific branch is mapped>` would get latest only for a corresponding branch from Team Foundation Server according to your workspace mapping

P.S. for 2nd point you can specify both TFS path or local path - tf resolves them fine in both directions